# Add xml prefix to soap request

Tags: android, soapui, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

How to add prefix tag to soap using ksoap?
I want to add : xmlns:cnx="http://db.hutt.com"

```
<v:Envelope  xmlns:cnx="http://db.hutt.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <v:Header>
            <authentication xmlns:n0="http://db.hutt.com">
                <userName>tutt</userName>
                <password>tutt@12345</password>
            </authentication>
        </v:Header>
        <v:Body>
            <cnx:get_tt xmlns="">
                <ttid>1</ttid>
            </cnx:get_tt>
        </v:Body>
    </v:Envelope>
```

Comment: After your edit your requests seem to be equivalent. What would you like to change?

Comment: The ttid element presumably does not belong to the namespace http://sdm.hott.com. You can add the ttid element with method: public SoapObject addProperty(String namespace,String name, Object value) and set the namespace to an empty string.

Comment: @KarelHusa I have edited the question. I can see that header should not have some tags while request in body should have the tag.

Comment: Can you please show the input and desired output? Is it ok to use groovy script?

Comment: @Rao Thanks. I have found the solution.

Comment: @KarelHusa  I found root cause using soapUI and then changing various element to find the cause. The reason was mainly the prefix in Envelope.

Comment: Hope you may find this simple groovy example useful. http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5188137487695872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it does not matter which ever tag you have example : v:Envelope or soapenv:Envelope. The soapserver will automatically parse it. Also, to add prefix in xml envelop you need to extend class *SoapSerializationEnvelope*.

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by suamatya on 4/11/2017.
 */

public class CustomSoapSerializationEnvelope extends SoapSerializationEnvelope {

    CustomSoapSerializationEnvelope(int version){
        super(version);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.setPrefix("i", xsi);
        writer.setPrefix("d", xsd);
        writer.setPrefix("c", enc);
        writer.setPrefix("v", env);
        writer.setPrefix("db","http://db.hott.com");
        writer.startTag(env, "Envelope");
        writer.startTag(env, "Header");
        writeHeader(writer);
        writer.endTag(env, "Header");
        writer.startTag(env, "Body");
        writeBody(writer);
        writer.endTag(env, "Body");
        writer.endTag(env, "Envelope");
    }
}
```